# Injected content script won't edit input tags in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, content-script, javascript-injection

I am trying to develop a custom password manager extension and using content script injection I manage to populate user_id and password input fields. However this worked on some webpages and did not on others. For webpage (chase.com) where this is not working, I even fetched tag id(s) by inspecting the individual input box and testing out if I can populate those fields, but it won't work.

I have a feeling that these fields are dynamic and somehow protected but somehow chrome and other browser are able to populate these fields by saved password, so there must be some way. Is there way to look into some open source browser code to understand this more ?

Here is my manifest.jason

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Chrome Plugin",
    "description": "This extension will manage passwords",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "http://192.168.1.27/"
    ]
}
```

background script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {id: "username", pass: "password"}, function(response) {});
        });
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "injected.js"});
    });
}, false);
```

injected content script:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i].type.indexOf("password") != -1) {
            fields[i].setAttribute("value", msg.pass);
        }
        if (fields[i].name.indexOf("user") != -1) {
            fields[i].setAttribute("value", msg.id)
        }
    }
});
```

When I call setAttribute function on the input fields, I get following logs on console. Please suggest what can be done or how I can debug this further.

```
[sendMessageClient] Sending command <resize>
chase-ux.min.js:65 Sign In Button Log: Sign In Type [cpo]
chase-ux.min.js:65 [sendMessageClient] Sending command <resize>
chase-ux.min.js:65 Sign In Button Log: Sign In Type [cpo]
```

Comment: Your background code makes relatively little sense (query, then query _again_, then a race condition between asynchronous message and script injection). You may want to refactor that with a [rubber ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs). But that's nitpicking, not your actual problem.

Comment: As for your actual problem, I suspect it has to do with page's JS binding data to the field, not directly reading the field value every time. So, you need to announce to the page (via DOM events) that the value changed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843563/using-pages-angular-js-in-chrome-extension (specifically triggering the `input` event) - if that helps, I'll close this as a dupe.

Comment: Don't use setAttribute at all, simply assign the .value property.

Comment: Thanks @Xan. Yes that seems to fix my error. You can dup this.

Pardon me for my coding skills, I am new to html/web coding, I appreciate pointing out issue, will surely refactor my code based on these.